Constructing Shift Functor on Chain Complexes - Alternating Differential
I've got a question pertaining to the construction of the shift functor on the chain complex category Ch$(\mathbf{A})$ (where $\mathbf{A}$ denotes an additive category).
It makes perfect sense to me why we'd define $\mathbf{A}[1]$ such that $(\mathbf{A}[1])^i\mapsto \mathbf{A}^{i+1}$, as well $(f[A])^i\mapsto f^{i+1}$. However, what doesn't make sense is why we define $d_{\mathbf{A}[1]}^{i}=-d_{\mathbf{A}}^{i+1}$. In particular, why is it necessary we include a negative sign?
This is a very basic question which has always haunted me, yet I struggle to find responses on here pertaining to it. If anybody could explain (or manage to find something), that would be greatly appreciated! The textbook I'm working through is by Achar, yet he seemingly skips over this aspect in the construction.
Thank you!

It is absolutely not necessary. Sign conventions vary a lot from one author to the other. I think I recall a joke quote attributed to Serre saying that keeping track of the signs in chain complex computations is the hardest part of the theory.

It is not strictly necessary but it ends up being very convenient. The convention has stuck for a reason. I realise that's a vague answer but you'll eventually appreciate it's not that annoying ( you lose nothing by adopting this convention ) and you gain benefits later down the line e.g. the signs appear when doing triangulated categories

@FShrike Interesting. This is genuinely been a major point of confusion for me in learning about chain complexes. But for it to be so arbitrary and simple...thank you for the response!

@CaptainLama ^^
